# Could not able to save the captured image to gallery using flutter_inappwebview

Tags: android, flutter, webview, flutter-inappwebview

Could not able to save the captured image to gallery using flutter_inappwebview

| Technology | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Flutter Version | 2.0.6 |
| flutter_inappwebview plugin Version | 5.3.2 |
| Android Versions | 8,9,10,11 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple file input element, including an accept filter that indicates you only want image files.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```